# managed targeted code requires \clr option

Tags: wrapper, firebreath

I am creating an application in Firebreath.
Below is the flow of my application:
C#-->Wrapper-->Firebreath-->Javascript

When I implement my wrapper in Firebreath(unmanaged code) then it throws the error as manged targeted code requires \clr option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wrapper needs to be build with /clr but be useable from a dll that is *not* /clr

Comment: Quick question! can I use COM callable wrappers instead of the managed wrapper c++/clI.If so! will the .tlb files be supported by the firebreath framework?@taxilian

Comment: you can use COM components from a firebreath dll, but it is not "supported by the firebreath framework". It should compile, if that's what you're asking -- the reason that /clr doesn't compile is that it actually changes the language.